# .dbml (Data class) in different namespace and file

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, dbml

I am new to LINQ to SQL and need some help on separating out data classes vs CRUD operation performed on database. I need to separate out Data Classes from .dbml designer file and move it to another namespace and preferably in new file.

Default behavior/parsing of .dbml file bundles all the data classes which is difficult to maintain.

Is there any way to decouple this mechanism.

Any help on this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not really worth the effort to learn LINQ-to-SQL, let alone learn how to teak it, if even possible. Do yourself a favor and turn to Entity Framework, code-first which is current technology and also gives you a lot more freedom. A dbml *is* difficult to maintain, period. Staying up-to-date with database changes is a disaster. Any manual changes to what it generates will only make things worse, no way that it will make things easier.

Comment: get https://www.linqpad.net- its free (no intelisence)